# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'true'

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

Why is SonarQube complaining about this part of the code?

[image]

I checked this code and not always this value is true.

```
public static void WriteJson(object value)
{
    decimal decimalValue = ((decimal?)value).Value;
    int intValue = (int)decimalValue;
    if (decimalValue == intValue)
        Console.WriteLine(intValue);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(decimalValue);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Why is SonarQube complaining about this?

Comment: Unless SonarQube has a magic wand that knows what you will pass in at runtime, it's wrong. And I don't like tools that lie to you, especially when they suggest refactorings that break the code.

Comment: Wild guess: SonarQube sees decimalValue cast to int and back to decimal, so it assumes (wrongly) that the value (of `(decimal)intValue`) is the original decimalValue - which would then mean that the condition is always true. Which would be correct if it *was* a cast, instead of a conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The false positive is related to an imperfection in our dataflow analysis engine - it does not take into account the casts between floating point and integer numbers (yet) and cannot recognize when a floating point number has been truncated.

I will try to elaborate a bit: the dataflow analysis engine tracks the values of the local variables in the analyzed methods, and when a new value is being assigned to a variable, the engine creates a special object that represents the actual value. When you assign one variable to another variable, that object remains the same. For example:

```
var x = 5; // the symbol of x is associated with value_0
var y = x; // the symbol of y is associated with value_0
if (x == y) // value_0 is compared with value_0 --> always true
```

The values we assign do not contain type information (yet) and we cannot detect (yet) changes in cases like yours:

```
var x = 5.5; // the symbol of x is associated with value_0
var y = (int)x; // the symbol of y is associated with value_0 (wrong)
if (x == y) // false positive
```

and we generate false positives, but they are relatively rare, because most casts do not generate new values.

Thanks for the feedback, we will be looking into that [in the near future](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/739).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SonarQube detects that you are assigning the same value to both variables, assume that value passed to method is equal to `2`

```
 1. decimal decimalValue = 2 
 2. int intValue = (int)decimalValue;
```

therefore `decimalValue = 2` and `intValue = 2`

The C# compiler will obviously cast it to `int` so in case you pass `2.5` the `if` comparision will not evaluate always to `true`. But most probably SonarQube  is just not aware about the casting. So it assumes always true.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at SonarQube, but I guess it is because SonarQube detects that you are setting `intValue` to the rounded form of `decimalValue`. And then again you are comparing `decimalValue` to the decimal form of `intValue`. So, in many cases, it will return 'true'.
To see how it will play out, suppose the decimalValue is "123.0". Then, the intValue will be exactly "123". Then, we compare "123.0"(The value of decimalValue) to "123.0"(The value of intValue after converting to decimal) with an "if" statement, which will return true. This will play out for all integers.

Comment: On the other hand, if `value` is 123.4, the condition will be false